# How many nxn diagonal real matrices which orthogonal

Tags: matrices

I was thinking that If a matrix is diagonal with entries belong to $ \mathbb{R}$ then it has to be a symmetric i.e. $ A^T = A$, but can I say that every diagonal matrix is orthogonal? I'm confused about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all real diagonal matrices are orthogonal. As you said, they are indeed self-adjoint ($A^t=A$), but that's not the same as orthogonality - $AA^t=I$.

If I want a diagonal matrix to be orthogonal, I need its inverse to be itself (since we have seen that diagonal matrices are self adjoint). Meaning - $A=A^{-1}$. There are only two matrices that satisfy this: $I$ and $-I$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider the definition of [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) and apply it on $D$, considering directly its diagonal entries.

***Partial Answer***

Not all the diagonal matrices are orthogonal.